# Can Occam's razor be applied in favor or presentism (vs eternalism)? Is presentism simpler?

Tags: time, occams-razor

If I understand correctly, both presentism and eternalism accept that spacetime can be described by the same coordinate system and following the same rules of physics. Moreover, both of them affirm that a huge amount of matter-energy (or information) exists distributed throughout space. The difference is that presentism posits that time is special in the sense that matter-energy only exists in a slice of time, that encompasses all of space. Whereas eternalism posits that matter-energy exists at all points of this coordinate system.

Now, my question is: can Occam's razor be applied in favor of presentism? The argument would go that both perspectives explain exactly the same facts and are compatible with all known science, but eternalism demands much more matter and energy to achieve the same explanatory result. Whereas presentism needs just a very tiny part of all that matter and energy to explain everything we see. Therefore it would seem that presentism would be the simplest theory. In other words, why would we need to assume much vaster quantities of matter-energy if we gain no explanatory power?

Comment: No, not really. As you can see from SEP's entry on [Simplicity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/), Occam's razor, as understood today, is about simplicity of *explanation*, not about quantities of matter involved in it. Eternalism fits better with modern relativistic physics, and so makes for a simpler overall explanation. Presentism has some [serious problems with relativity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/#RelaPhys), and requires unnatural extra constructs, such as the privileged frame, to be reconciled with it.

Comment: "It has often been commented by physicists that Einstein’s GTR {thus} reintroduced the relations of absolute simultaneity that his STR had denied". Craig W., Simth Q, 2007. *Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity*,p.8 .

Comment: Two events at the same place and time are simultaneous for all under gtr and str. From here, consider two events at the same time and place not as two events at all but as one: While it’s true that gtr allows for absolute simultaneity, there are still events which are simultaneous for some observers but not others under gtr (such events are not absolutely simultaneous). So absolute simultaneity doesnt carry the weight people often think. And observers dont generally agree about the time between two events, even two absolutely simultaneous events. There is no single timeline, still spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see where you are going with this matter and energy story, but it seems quite clear that presentism mobilizes less unnecessary entities than eternalism, so unless there is something that it can't explain, Occam's razor should favor it.

Under presentism, only exists the present, an ensemble of stuff that moves and change. Because of the conservation of energy stuff keeps moving uniformly, unless it bumps into other stuff.

Time is only the perception of the uniform movement of stuff, for example how long it takes for a planet rotating at constant speed to complete one revolution is one day. Timespace becomes a necessary concept because when stuff moves uniformly into a curved space, the perception its movement from far away changes.

Future is just the consequence of change. It does not need to "be" anywhere, it just happens. Past is just how we remember things were before changing. It does not need  to "go" anywhere. We can imagine the future or the past by applying our knowledge of the laws of change on the present situation (retroactively in the case of past, but the procedure is the same), yet it is merely extrapolated information from the present state of things.

Eternalism, on the other hand, requires a place for the past and future to be, a reason for time to pass, a reason for why we perceive only the present. It seems to raise many more questions that it answers, which is precisely what Occam's razor is designed to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately presentism omits many necessary entities along with the unnecessary ones. The physical fact of the relativity of simultaneity would be impossible in a presentist universe where the past does not exist.

Comment: I dont see why. Take the common exemple of the train hit by thunder at both ends while observed simultaneously by an observer in the train and another standing near the railway: it does not require any concept of abstract past, just photons moving at constant speed hitting observers in motion relative to each other.

Comment: Subjective failure to comprehend the issue doesn’t mean the issue doesn’t exist, lol. It’s not about when the photons hit the observers. A lightning detector in the observer’s initial frame would record the lightning strikes as simultaneous; lightning detectors aboard the train (like something attached to the carriage) would record different times for the strikes. The “presents” experienced in both frames are *physically*, not just perceptually, different.

Comment: Each lightning is perceived by both observers in a different sequence, but it is only because the observers are moving relative to each other. The photons move exactly in the same way, and this is why there is no privileged frame of reference. Because no information goes faster than light, both observers can't know any better than what they see and come to different conclusions about the sequence of events. Pry explain why it requires the existence of some "past" time to store information? Please remember, when people are not convinced, it MIGHT be because you're not making sense ^^

Comment: If basic relativity “isn’t making sense” to you, is that Einstein’s fault, or your fault?  Your continuing conflation of differences in “appearance simultaneity” with relativistic failure of absolute simultaneity (see https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/Special_relativity_rel_sim/index.html) suggests that you really have failed to understand the issue. The lack of absolute simultaneity is physically real, and fatal to presentist theories of space-time.

Comment: Your link says nothing but exactly what I say... I mean... Have you read it before sharing? Have you considered even one second that YOUR understanding might be flawed? How can one be so smug ? The Dunning Krugger is strong with this one...

Comment: The "who is right" section is particularly relevant: observers in a different frame of reference or far apart can't agree on the simultaneity of events because signals of those events take time to reach them, and this time depends on their distance and motion relative to the event. There is nothing here that can't be explained under presentism. You are just reading way too much into it.

Comment: If the "present" is *physically different* for every two observers--not just different in appearance, but actuality, as it is in special relativity--it renders the presentist model of the "true present" incoherent: there is no such animal. There are only *relative* "presents", a different one for each inertial frame, and different presents will necessarily disagree on the order of some events. Also, matter inside a black hole may travel backwards in time, which presentism also can't account for: https://www.einstein-online.info/en/spotlight/changing_places/

Comment: Man, you just don't understand relativity. The present is not physically different, just perceived differently. Plus, even if you were right about relativity (which you are not), where are the "past" and the "future" in your model? If you have no past and no future, it's presentism. You don't even get what presentism is. Also, please go look into a black hole and come back to tell us what happens inside before speculating about it. I think "may" is a keyword here. As long as it merely "may", I don't care. Sorry, not sorry.

Comment: Also, the question was about Occam's razor. If presentism could not account for the facts observed (which you have still not demonstrated) then Occam's razor need not apply, so our discution is irrelevant anyway. Even that you didn't get... But yeah, disagreeing with you equal disagreeing with Einstein... Totally not smug and pompous.

Comment: "may" actually means "can and does" in this context. Matter inside a black hole travels backwards in time. It's also not uncommon to consider particles that travel backwards in time in quantum mechanics, at least for brief jumps. We can observe time's arrow directly by firing a light pulse away from ourselves; "past" events are those we remember (when the pulse was closer), "future" ones are ones we haven't experienced yet (when the pulse will be farther).

Comment: The present is physically, actually different for different observers. Time dilation between observers and events at different velocities. Under gtr but not str there are events that are absolutely simultaneous (all observers see them as simultaneous). So in a way there is a present. However, no individual observer can tell which of the simultaneous events that he observes are also simultaneous for all other observers, so it isnt much of a present. Im w Rivers on this one.

Comment: @albrown no, the present appears different to distant observers but locally there is only one event happening. The probe landing on mars might be already landed while the observer on earth still sees it entering the atmosphere because light takes a few minutes to reach them. But locally the probe IS landed, and this is what the observer will see happen after waiting a few minutes. And it will never happen that the probe lands locally but the observer sees it crash.

Comment: No. You do not understand relativity. Really. Youre not alone in that regard though.

Comment: @albrown with such powerful arguments, I can do nothing but surrender...

Comment: **Time itself passes at different rates for different observers**. And for observer A vs B: two rates of time for different sequences events can be relatively different to each other. In other words, the duration between events 1 and 2 might be greater than the duration between events 3 and 4 for one observer but not for another. Thank you for submitting  . Have a great day, even if it is longer or shorter than my day.

Comment: @albrown Yes. How does that mean that reality is physically different for two distant observers and not simply their perception of it ? Yes, people far from each other might not agree on the order of distant events or even how long they have been appart from each other, but locally all ambiguities are left. Bob on Alpha Centauri and Alice on Earth might disagree about when Roger starts his voyage back from Betelgeuse and how long it took, but if Bob comes back to Earth first they can they can all agree on when Roger arrives. Don't get carried on by high school level explanations of relativity.

Comment: @armand and youre aware that different observers disagree about the mass of something ?

Comment: @albrown yeah. Mass, size, time, you name it. My answer is the same. All of those people can agree when in the same frame of reference, and if they know the parameters of an object in the other frame they can use relativity formulas and find what mass the object would have if in their frame. That's why I find it much more parsimonious to consider there is but one reality, and problems linked to observations rather than to construe some bloated theory of different realities that can separate and merge back together because reasons. Let's not forget the original question was about Occam's razor.

Comment: Im not sure we were talking about multiple realities. I thought you disagreed with the statement that time passes at different rates in different frames. If not then my misread

Answer (score 0):

In its original form, the razor went something like, "Do not multiply entities unnecessarily." If theory *T*<sub>1</sub> requires *n* unobservables and theory *T*<sub>2</sub> requires *m* unobservables, and if *n* < *m*, then *T*<sub>1</sub> is preferable (modulo the razor).

Now with presentism, we don't have all times given. But with eternalism, is it correct to speak of "times" anymore, or just the one all-encompassing eternal time? One could, then, formulate presentism and eternalism such that there is only one actually existent temporal object (so to speak) required by either theory, in which case adjudicating between the theories can't default to applying the razor to them.

(Or so it seems, on the face of it, to me. However, one might object, "The temporal object required by eternalism is potentially infinitely larger than the one required by presentism; it has more *parts* than the 'moving spotlight.'" I have no reply to that objection at the time being, except to say that even the "moving spotlight" might be otherwise internally divisible into infinitesimal parts, of which there would therefore be infinitely many even if the "spotlight" were a single integral unit of time.)

Answer (score -1):

Occam’s razor would seem to (slightly) favor eternalism over presentism, if anything. As Conifold points out in the comments, the relativity of simultaneity as theorized by Einstein and verified by experiment would seem to be a fatal blow to any strict presentist theory. Yet eternalism would seem to conflict with both quantum physics (Bell’s theorem against hidden variables) and our everyday experience of free will. One potential reconciliation is that of the “growing block universe”. A presentist might claim a version of the growing block universe where parts of the block “get deleted” or cease to exist gives the necessary correction to presentist theory, although it’s not clear why or how they would get deleted.

Comment: Are you saying eternalism would require hidden variables, so that the lack of them conflicts with eternalism? If so, why?

Comment: @hypnosufi Quantum mechanics makes probabilistic predictions about the future which are incompatible with deterministic explanations, one of which is Bell’s theorem.

Comment: Eternalism is not the same as determinism, eternalism just says that past, present, and future all have the same ontological status (past and future things 'exist' in exactly the same sense as present ones), not that later states of the world can be perfectly predicted from earlier ones. Consider a row of numbers on a piece of paper sitting in front of you--all the printed symbols representing the numbers are equally real, even if the numbers don't follow a rule such that later ones can be predicted from earlier ones.

Comment: Also, Bell's theorem only shows that quantum mechanics is incompatible with local hidden variable theories where every measurement has a single definite outcome, it doesn't rule out Bohmian mechanics or the many-worlds interpretation, which are both deterministic.

Comment: @hypnosifI To say that the future exists and is real and fixed is to say that the future is determined from the beginning. A deterministic universe need not be predictable-in-practice, or even predictable-in-principle, from inside of itself in order to be deterministic. To go with your sequence analogy, there may not be a way of telling what the next symbol is from the previous ones; but someone wrote down all the symbols before, and if you could have watched them do that, you would be able to predict the sequence perfectly.

Comment: @Hypnosifl As "interpretations", Bohmian mechanics and many-worlds aren't testable or falsifiable. I don't consider them any more compelling than superdeterminism as an explanation for the universe as we actually observe it.

Comment: "A deterministic universe need not be predictable-in-practice, or even predictable-in-principle" It *does* need to be predictable-in-principle (by a Laplacian demon, say) according to how philosophers generally define the term "deterministic", have you considered that your understanding of the word just differs from the mainstream philosophical usage? And local hidden variables theories are deterministic in exactly that predictable-in-principle sense, that's what Bell's theorem is ruling out, nothing in the theorem rules out the idea that future facts already have a definite truth-value.

Comment: "Bohmian mechanics and many-worlds aren't testable or falsifiable" No, but neither it is it testable or falsifiable that QM contains genuine randomness, that is itself dependent on a particular choice of untestable interpretation.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Wouldn't Occam's razor suggest that something like quantum mechanics that *seemed* genuinely random, **was**, unless we could prove otherwise?  I would consider predeterminism as having little meaningful difference from the definition of determinism you're insisting on here, although your patience for hairsplitting may be much higher than mine. Your sequence of numbers example is obviously an instance of predeterminism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predeterminism

Comment: I don't think this is hairsplitting since you brought up Bell's theorem, which is about ruling out local hidden variables theories which are deterministic in the physicist's sense (i.e. the idea that if a Laplacean demon knew the complete physical state of the universe at an earlier time, including hidden variables, there would be some physical laws they could use to perfectly predict the universe's state at a later time), but has nothing whatsoever to do with the philosophical question of predeterminism. So this is a good illustration of why it confuses certain issues to conflate them.

Comment: @Hypnosifl My point is that eternalism conflicts with all but predeterministic theories, and determinism (even according to your particular definition) is a type of predeterminism, although perhaps not vice versa.

Comment: Right, the "not vice versa" is key, if predeterminism does not necessarily imply determinism, then a physics theorem that rules out deterministic theories (really just a specific class of deterministic theories, but never mind that now) shouldn't be taken to rule out predeterminism. Think of a Venn diagram with a circle labeled "determinism" that lies entirely inside a larger circle labeled "predeterminism"--showing that our world doesn't lie in the smaller circle doesn't rule out the possibility it lies in the larger circle.

Comment: @HypnosifI I didn’t go into detail about this in my answer but what I’m saying is that if quantum mechanics is truly random—if there’s no underlying predeterminism happening behind the scenes, *of any kind*—that conflicts with eternalism. I came down less hard on eternalism than presentism because of that kind of philosophical question: it could be that there actually is predeterminism in the universe, but that we are not in a position to “see” it directly.

Comment: How could b-theorists ever take this into account in any way? I guess the ‘truly random’ and ‘exists’ dont seem as incompatible to me as to rivers. Im mostly w hypno on this one. Maybe youre saying quantum mechanics argues against all types of b-theory, but I dont see that

Comment: `what I’m saying is that if quantum mechanics is truly random—if there’s no underlying predeterminism happening behind the scenes, *of any kind*—that conflicts with eternalism.` But that's what Hypno is arguing - that's NOT what Bell's theorem rules out. If it rules out anything, it rules out Determinism in the sense of calculating future states from past states, NOT predeterminism in the sense that the future states are decided.

Comment: However, as others have stated, Bell's Theorem doesn't necessarily rule out that flavor of determinism anyway.